# Parse single log line with awk

Tags: apache, parsing, logging, awk

I am trying to find a way to parse a single (apache) log line into blocks.
I know I can change apache config to create a json, but I believe this awk knowledge will help me in the future.

So I have this:

```
127.0.1.1:80 187.207.66.53 - - [18/Jan/2021:18:28:22 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2352 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
```

And want to change it into this:

```
127.0.1.1:80
187.207.66.53
-
-
[18/Jan/2021:18:28:22 +0100]
"GET / HTTP/1.1"
200
2352
[...]
```

So basically I believe I need to set up different field separators, am I right?

```
-F '[<fieldSeparator1>|<fieldSeparator2> ]' '{
for (i = 1; i<= NF; i++)
print $i
}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ awk '
    match($0,/(\S+) (\S+) (\S+) (\S+) (\[[^]]*]) ("[^"]*") (\S+) (\S+) ("[^"]*") ("[^"]*")/,f) {
        for (i=1; i in f; i++) {
            print f[i]
        }
    }
' file
127.0.1.1:80
187.207.66.53
-
-
[18/Jan/2021:18:28:22 +0100]
"GET / HTTP/1.1"
200
2352
"-"
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: Tried it, but I got this:
awk: line 2: syntax error at or near ,

Comment: Then you made a mistake copy/pasting the script or you aren't using GNU awk as I mentioned in the answer is required. What does `awk --version` tell you?

Comment: You are right mister, awk in Raspbian failed, the one in my centos vm works fine :)
So 'f' is an array, I thought it was a mistake in 'printf'.

Comment: Yes, f is the array of fields I'm populating with the regexp in match().

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk and a regex. **Tested only with your example.**

```
awk '{$1=$1; print}' OFS='\n' FPAT='"[^"]*"|\\[[^]]*]|[0-9:.]+|-' file
```

> `FPAT`: A  regular  expression describing the contents of the fields in a record.  When set, gawk parses the
> input into fields, where the fields match the regular expression, instead of using the value  of  FS
> as the field separator.

Output:

```
127.0.1.1:80
187.207.66.53
-
-
[18/Jan/2021:18:28:22 +0100]
"GET / HTTP/1.1"
200
2352
"-"
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
```

See: `man awk` and [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)